# Android Studio: Chat box layout

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout

I want to edit a TextView widget in such way that it looks like a message box (see the picture)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ueWX.png). However, right now I only have a rectangle shape with rounded corners, but I want it to look exactly like the picture.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

use 9-patch image provided by android studio itself. because the edittext scale according to the text entered by user. 9-patch can scale the image properly. But you have to first create the image using photoshop or some other software. google it. you will find.

[tutorial for 9 patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)